# Angular code not running when injected via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I am pretty new to Angular, and hence finding my way around.

I understand that the ng-controller would run on the page load. The angular HTML elements would be updated depending on the actions of ng-controller.

I would like to inject my html code, which consists of the ng-controller, via AJAX. Meaning that this will be injected after the page has been loaded.

I noticed that my angular code does not get executed. Is there a way I can reinit angular ? Or register the new controller and run it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Angular does not recognise any dom manipulation you do with jquery. For example appending to dom etc.

You need to compile and link any html you want to inject that way. I would say you want to use a directive to do it.

Sample code (in case you are doing it from within controller)

```
var template = '<div ng-repeat="a in [1,2,3,4]">{{a}}</div>'
var element_to_add =  angular.element(template)
var linkFn = $compile(element_to_add);
linkFn($scope);

var target_element = $(css_selector)
target_element.html(element_to_add)// or target_element.append(element_to_add)
```

But like I said, it is not a good idea to append to dom from controller. Do this in a directive.

Answer (score 0):

While this might not be the exact solution you're looking for, I'm sure this can be a close enough solution;

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/customers',
        {
            templateUrl: '/app/views/template.html',
            resolve: resolveController('/app/controllers/dynamicController.js')
        });
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain that please ? Where should this be placed ?

Comment: When you declare you angular app: `var app = angular.module(…)`, you should define the routes of the app itself: `app.run(…)`. More details: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute